# How to replicate/achieve Text='<% #Bind("field") %>' by only using code behind? (asp.net C#)

Tags: asp.net, gridview, controls, bind, datafield

I am creating a custom control which takes in a filepath (string) to an xml file and a dictionary of column headers, column fields and creates a gridview dynamically with CRUD operations. What I want to know is how to replicate/achieve Text='<% #Bind("field") %>' by only using code behind?

I was thinking of trying:

```
Dictionary<string, string> columns = new Dictionary<string, string>();

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> column in columns)
            {
                BoundField bField = new BoundField();
                bField.DataField = column.Value;
                bField.HeaderText = column.Key;
                GridView1.Columns.Add(bField);
            }
```

I'm open to suggestions as to either using .DataField or Text='<% #Bind("field") %>' or any way I haven't thought of if it achieves the end goal. As with the CRUD, can anyone recommend a good way to do this? Maybe dynamically inserting textbox and label controls into the gridview? I am using Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You override the ItemDataBound event. If you're thinking about dynamically adding controls to each row, you're better off using a different kind of templated control such as a Repeater.

*UPDATE* - an example

First make sure you handle the RowDataBound event (not ItemDataBound my bad, that's for the DataGrid): -

```
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        grid.RowDataBound += grid_RowDataBound;
```

Set up your columns from your dictionary of column names (I've used a string array, but you get the idea): -

```
        var columns = new string[] { "Column 1", "Column 2", "Column 3" };

        foreach (var columnName in columns)
        {
            grid.Columns.Add(new BoundField { HeaderText = columnName });
        }
```

Then in the RowDataBound event: -

```
    void grid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            var data = ({your object type})e.Row.DataItem;

            e.Row.Cells[0].Text = data.{fieldname};
            e.Row.Cells[1].Text = data.{fieldname};
            .
            .
            .
            e.Row.Cells[n].Text = {something};
        }
    }
```

Comment: An example would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Would you be able to provide either a more detailed example or another example in the RowDataBound event on how to accomplish the '= data.{fieldname}' if the field names are for example in a string array and not hardcoded in. I hope this makes sense. I can successfully display the data but I need to make sure it will be able to handle CRUD operations.

Comment: If you're going use a string array as the data source for your GridView, you're going to have to "handle CRUD operations" manually and you're not really using the GridView data binding effectively. Here's a couple of articles explaining how to properly handle CRUD operations with a GridView - DotNetGallery http://bit.ly/1vQTxIS and C-SharpCorner http://bit.ly/1unxFQJ. If you're around later I'm happy to help via a chat if you want